# Preserve OPNsense logs after a reboot

Tags: boot, logging, opnsense

OPNsense just got stuck (or maybe DOSed, but I can’t tell because of missing logs), and I had to reboot from the serial console to restore functionality quickly.

After the system came back up trouble-free, I wanted to check the logs and found the earliest entries were from the reboot. Everything from before the reboot seems to have been discarded, or never persisted to disk in the first place.

I cannot find any setting to preserve logs across a reboot in **System:Settings:Logging**, where I would expect it. There is a setting called **Preserve logs (Days)**, which is blank  and thus should default to 31 days, but this obviously had no effect.

(In case someone is telling me that I should fix the failure rather than do a full reboot – well and fair, but apart from the fact that it may take longer to figure out what crashed than reboot the box, what would I do if I lose all access to the system, including to the serial console?)

Is there a setting that tells OPNsense to persist logs across reboots, at least for the retention period?